# Using system-wide python via reticulate

Tags: r, rstudio, reticulate

My `~/.Renviron` file has the following contents:

```
RETICULATE_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python3"
```

However, when I run the following code from inside RStudio, I get the error shown below:

```r
library(reticulate)

py_config()

#> Error: could not find a Python environment for /usr/bin/python3
```

Any help?

Comment: You need to set up a virtual environment: `use_virtualenv("myenv")`. You can create one with `virtualenv_create` (`reticulate` package). [Read here for examples with and without Conda/Anaconda](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/python_packages.html).

Comment: Thanks, @Kat. I have just created the environment with `virtualenv_create("r-reticulate")`. However, when running `use_virtualenv("r-reticulate"); py_config()`, I get the same error message: `Error: could not find a Python environment for /usr/bin/python3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following fixes the problem:

```
Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "/home/x/.virtualenvs/r.reticulate/bin/python")
library(reticulate)
```